# Create from file gives CondaHTTPError: HTTP 404 NOT FOUND

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I created an Anaconda Python Conda environment and exported a spec file so I could re-install the exact same environment at a later date if necessary using the command `conda list --explicit`. That day is today, but I'm disappointed to see that one of the files isn't available and was replaced with a newer version:

https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/gdal-2.1.3-np111py35_vc14_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/gdal-2.1.3-np111py35_vc14_7.tar.bz2

Conda encounters an error because the link is broken and then it retries unsuccessfully several times:

```
CondaError: CondaHTTPError: HTTP 404  NOT FOUND for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/gdal-2.1.3-np111py35_vc14_0.tar.bz2
Elapsed: 00:01.270000
CF-RAY: 3fa8f7eb093298a1-LAX

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTPerrors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
```

Four-part question:

1. Are spec files intended only for very short term usage?
2. Should I be archiving each .bz2 file independently to be able to recreate the environment later?
3. Is there a tool available to help me do this, or should I look through the folders and manually find what I need and copy it and conda install each one?
4. Is there a better way to check the validity of all the links of a spec file other than attempting to install it and watching it crash? It looks like conda will check to see if it has already downloaded the same file in another environment and won't attempt another download and the broken link could be hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In conda channels, there is no guarantee that the versions of the tools you use will be maintained forever. For example, if a bug is found in a tool, it will be corrected and a newer version will be put in place of the old version.

`conda list --explicit` is not a very good way to export environments as, you said it, it will only work for a very short term. Moreover, it is not portable to other OS. I would recommend `conda env export` or `conda list --export` as stated in the conda doc: https://conda.io/docs/commands/env/conda-env-export.html 
.This way, the versions of the tools will be kept but not the full URL where each package can be downloaded and which are likely to change often.

So to answer

Q1:
If you export environments the right way, you can use them over time. You can never be sure that the version of a tool you used 10 years ago will still be available, but conda will tell you this when importing your environment.

Q2:
You can create you own conda channel and package whatever tool you want with fixed versions. But the question is: "do you really need this?". It means you get no upgrade for the tools you used. Sometimes it is preferable to update your code and use a newer version of the tool than to keep an old bugged version or forget the improvements.

I have never tested but on another post I read that environments are self contained in one folder, `$CONDA_HOME/envs/[your_env]` and that this folder can be copied directly in another conda installation if it's the same architecture (linux64,windows,OSX...).

Q3:
There is no tool for this apart from the `conda env export`. By the way, I think all downloaded packages are in `$CONDA_HOME/pkgs`.

Q4:
No, since it is a not a good way to export your environments. For information, conda does not download multiple times the same packages for different environments. It reuses the already installed packages. You have the possibility to add a file called `.condarc` in your home and put in that file `allow_softlinks: false`. This will tell conda to reinstall any package needed in the installation of a new environment and not to link the tools already installed in other envs.

Answer (score 2):

execute following command, it will resolve the issue:

```
conda config --remove-key channels
conda config --append channels conda-forge --append channels bioconda --append 
channels defaults
```

Also note that I intentionally left out the r channel you currently have in your channel list. You don't need to and shouldn't use that channel (since it actually lowers performance of the solver) since the R packages are already part of the defaults multichannel as https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r.